# quick basic question: workflow with SPD 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, sharepoint-on-prem

SPdesigner 2013 forces you to add a condition to any workflow. If I recall in SPD 2010 you could delete the portion and still have a functioning workflow.

At times you do not need a 'condition' and you leave the workflow run on simply every entry.

In this case what is the best thing to do with the condition? My current favourite is to put (all authenticated users) is a valid sharepoint user.

Is this correct? what do you place as a condition if you do not have a real condition?

In the image below I deleted the condition that I was forced to place
[image]

Comment: Can you please post a screen capture?

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: I'm using SPD 2013 and can create action workflows without any conditions.  I can also delete conditions from workflows which previously had a condition/action.  Does it not let you highlight that entire "insert a condition" line and delete?  What happens when you click below that and insert an action?  Does it automatically insert the condition line?

Comment: If I delete the condition it gives me the red text in the image.

Comment: You need to get rid of the entire box that the condition goes in.  Try moving your "create item" line up or down until it is outside that box, then select and delete that box.

Comment: You can also try clicking below that entire box (right above 'transition to stage' and insert an action.  If it allows you to do that without automatically inserting the condition piece (which it does on my end) you can just copy/paste your action into that space and completely delete the previous condition/action box.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this in my environment.

[image]

If you are still stuck then use a condition `1 equals 1`

**Edit**

I was able to repro your scenario. The steps I followed

1. Insert a condition
2. Inside the condition block add a create list item action
3. Then delete the condition
4. Clicked on check errors

[image]

**Fix**

1. Select the condition box and hit delete button on keyboard

Comment: ok, so why when the condition is deleted I get an error? The condition was pointless to the workflow execution.

Comment: Can't you select the box and delete?

Comment: @susan possibly because there is still a "condition placeholder" in the workflow, if that makes sense?  Try moving your "create item" line up until it is outside of the box that has "insert condition", then highlight and delete the box with "insert condition".